# Android String Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-keystore

I want to encrypt and decrypt a `String` from an `EditText` using `AndroidKeyStore`. My problem is that at the decrypt process is get a `BadPaddingException`.

Key generator code:

```
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

        KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ALIAS, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT).
                setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM).setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE).build();

        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Encryption code:

```
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);

            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(ALIAS, null);
            SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            cipherIV = cipher.getIV();

            plainText.setText(new String(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Decryption code:

```
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            keyStore.load(null);

            final KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(ALIAS, null);
            final SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, cipherIV);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec);

            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            plainText.setText(new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is in error:

```
plainText.setText(new String(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

If we break it apart, we have something like

```
byte [] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
plainText.setText(new String(cipherBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The problem is that `cipherBytes` is a sequence of arbitrary bytes rather than the characters of a string. The String constructor will silently replace invalid characters with something else, a process which corrupts the data.

If you want to display the cipher bytes or otherwise send it to a character oriented channel you must *encode* it. Typically encodings are base64 or hex. To decrypt the String you must then decode it to bytes first and then decrypt it.

Example:

```
byte [] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
plainText.setText(Base64.encodeToString(cipherBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

And on decrypt:

```
byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.decode(plainText.getText().toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This line may not work well because of the call of `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. If your `EditText` is hex representation, try to convert it to string and then invoke `getBytes()`. E.g.

```
public static byte[] convertHexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {

    int l = hexString.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[l/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        data[i/2] = (byte)((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }

    return data;
}
```